# Grouping nodes in puppet

Tags: puppet

In my site.pp manifest, I have the following

```
import "nodes/*.pp"
```

This lets me nicely create separate files for different groups. However, inside each .pp file, i still have to explicitly set the name of the nodes I want to apply modules and classes to, as so:

```
node puppet-client-1 {
  include testmodule
}
```

My question is, How do I group a number of nodes together, and then apply modules and/or classes to that node group? eg:

```
group testgroup{
  puppet-client1
  puppet-client2
}

node webservers
{
  include testmodule
}
```

While I am here, my log is spitting out this:

```
The use of 'import' is deprecated at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:2
```

If this is deprecated, how do I split out my manifest files into groups?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways:

1) Multiple node names in one line:

```
node 'puppet-client1', 'puppet-client2' {
    include testmodule
}
```

2)  Nodes can be defined with regexes, e.g.:

```
node /^puppet-client[0-9]+/{
  include testmodule
}
```

but that depends on a suitable host naming scheme.

You can see the official documentation for [node definitions](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_node_definitions.html).

Comment: Late follow up, but there is no way to create a group of nodes that you can then later reference?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to actually write an ENC - an [External Node Classifier](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/nodes_external.html) which will allow you to abstract out your 'groups' to a simple script written in any language you're comfortable with.

Note that this returns **classes** and **parameters**, so this can be used to make Puppet far more ansible-like, so you get the best of both worlds.

From the documentation, the script is run with the param of the node to be classified, and simply returns a YAML description of classes and params to be applied.